# Xlsxwriter - use variable in table to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation, xlsxwriter

I'm using pandas concat to merge several dataframe (tables) to an excel document.
I use Xlsxwriter for the excel output.

My question is, in the code below I specify the range for the table in excel using the `worksheet.add_table('A1:D26')`. That works for this example file. But in the final document the amount of dataframes depends on the input. So sometimes it's df1 till df5. Than is 26 lines enough. But it can also be less, maybe 1 or 2 dataframes or a lot more. 
Can I use a variable instead of D26?

For example `worksheet.add_table('A1:Dx')`, where x is defined by the userinput?

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['X','1','2','3'],
                    '1':['1','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '2':['2','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '3':['3','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '4':['','','','']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['X','1','2','3'],
                    '1':['1','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '2':['2','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '3':['3','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '4':['','','','']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['X','1','2','3'],
                    '1':['1','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '2':['2','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '3':['3','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '4':['','','','']})

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['X','1','2','3'],
                    '1':['1','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '2':['2','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '3':['3','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '4':['','','','']})

df5 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['X','1','2','3'],
                    '1':['1','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '2':['2','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '3':['3','☐','☐','☐'],
                    '4':['','','','']})

result = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], axis=1)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('output')
worksheet.add_table('A1:D26', {'data': result.values.T.tolist(),'style': 'None', 'header_row': False})

workbook.close()
```

Comment: You could use built in pandas method df.to_excel('name.xlsx') it will output all of your dataframe to an Excel file. And yes you can pass in variables instead of D26, please, look into f strings or other string formatting options python provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a format string.  Here I define x1 and x2, then insert them into your cell range string using `%d` to specify integer format.  The string is followed by `% (<arg1>,<arg2>)`.

```
x1 = 2
x2 = 27
worksheet.add_table('A%d:D%d'%(x1,x2), {'data': result.values.T.tolist(),'style': 'None', 'header_row': False})
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example `worksheet.add_table('A1:Dx')`, where x is defined by the userinput?

In almost all cases XlsxWriter methods support two forms of notation to designate the position of cells: Row-column notation and A1 notation.

In `add_table()` both row-column and A1 style notation are supported. The following are equivalent:

```py
worksheet.add_table(2, 1, 6, 5, { ... })
worksheet.add_table('B3:F7',    { ... })
```

So for your case your can use:

```py
worksheet.add_table(0, 0, row_num, 4, { ... })  # A1:Dx
```

Where `row_num` is a zero indexed number based on the length of your dataframe or some other input variable.